# What is a wheel in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel

After browsing through some pages still I'm not clear with the wheel purpose during the installation of any library. Can someone explain me in easily understandable way.

> Failed to build pandas numpy
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: https://pythonwheels.com/

Comment: In short, its a python install package. See https://pythonwheels.com/ and https://pypi.org/project/wheel/.

Comment: @tdelaney Is a wheel a pre-build/binary python package for a specific platform ?

Comment: @SebMa - Yes, wheel is a binary package as defined in [PEP427](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/). It will hold platform independent .py files and if there is a need for compiling C files, it could have C source or built binaries. One wheel can hold binaries for many systems.

Answer (score 2):

The wheels module helps build other packages if you're having issues try the following.

```
pip install wheel --upgrade
```